# 18.04: JavaFx not working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, javafx

I just recently joined the Linux familly and have been transitionning from windows pretty well but i've just hurt myself to a somewhat strange problem while trying to dev on javafx.

I am currently working with intelliJ, apparently the graphic card isn't used correctly, i've tried to research the cause problem on some forums and got some lead ; giving me this:

Failed Graphics Hardware Qualifier check.

System GPU doesn't meet the es2 pipe requirement

GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline: error initializing pipeline com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline

I Have a GP107M[GTX 1050 Mobile],an i7 7th gen 24Gigs of Ram

Thank you for reading !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp i found the culprit, i somehow fycked up my first ubuntu install by not allowing a swapping space big enough , by doing so followed a random tuto to start with the "nomodeset" in recovery mode , thus making it kinda work but only in recovery , but deactivacting the graphic card options and making it impossible for sofwares to get a proper acces to it , giving me the JavaFx bug !

As for my solve : Complete and utter format of my pc , re-burning my USB-install key,correctly installing it with a Linux Swap big enough and yea that's pretty much it !